# How does this zsh parameter expansion work?

Tags: zsh

I came across a zsh script which contains this parameter expansion

```
${LBUFFER%%(#m)[_a-zA-Z0-9]#}
```

For anyone wanting to know the context this expression lives in, its part of a [zle widget function that provides vim like abbreviations](http://zshwiki.org/home/examples/zleiab)

Its basic form is obviously a suffix trim.  i.e. `${name%%pattern}`

i.e. from `man zshexpn` - PARAMETER EXPANSION

> ```
>    ${name%pattern}
>    ${name%%pattern} 
>    If the pattern matches the end of the value of name,  then  sub‐
>       stitute the value of name with the matched portion deleted;
>      [...]
> ```

regarding the *parameter expansion flag* `(#m)`: from `man zshexpn`

> ```
>    #      Evaluate the resulting words as numeric expressions  and    output
>       the  characters  corresponding  to  the resulting integer.  Note
>       that this form is entirely distinct from use of  the  #  without
>       parentheses.
>
>
>    m      Only  useful together with one of the flags l or r or with the #
>       length operator when the MULTIBYTE option is in effect.  Use the
>       character  width  reported by the system in calculating how much
>       of the string it occupies or the overall length of  the  string.
>       Most printable characters have a width of one unit, however cer‐
>       tain Asian character sets and certain special effects use  wider
>       characters; combining characters have zero width.  Non-printable
>       characters are arbitrarily counted as zero width; how they would
>       actually be displayed will vary.
> ```

regarding the `[_a-zA-Z0-9]#` part, this is obviously the pattern that gets removed from the end of the `LBUFFER` string , but is this a regex pattern or some regex globbing hybrid?
Is it part of the zsh-specific "extended_glob" patterns?, i.e. from `man zshoptions`

> ```
>    EXTENDED_GLOB
>       Treat  the  `#',  `~' and `^' characters as part of patterns for
>       filename generation, etc.  (An initial unquoted `~' always  pro‐
>       duces named directory expansion.)
> ```

what does this zsh parameter expansion do?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that is a zsh "extended glob" expression.

i.e. from `man zshexpn`

> Globbing Flags
>          There are various flags which affect any text to their right up to  the
>          end  of  the enclosing group or to the end of the pattern; they require
>          the EXTENDED_GLOB option. All take the form (#X) where X may  have  one
>          of the following forms:
>
> [...]
>          m
>        Set references to the match data for the entire string  matched;
>           this is similar to backreferencing and does not work in filename
>             generation.  The flag must be in effect at the end of  the  pat‐
>             tern, i.e. not local to a group. The parameters $MATCH,  $MBEGIN
>             and $MEND will be set to the string matched and to  the  indices
>             of  the  beginning and end of the string, respectively.  This is
>             most useful in parameter substitutions, as otherwise the  string
>           matched is obvious.
>
> For example,
>
> ```
>        arr=(veldt jynx grimps waqf zho buck)
>        print ${arr//(#m)[aeiou]/${(U)MATCH}}
> ```
>
> forces  all the matches (i.e. all vowels) into uppercase, print‐
>      ing `vEldt jynx grImps wAqf zhO bUck'.
>       Unlike backreferences, there is no speed penalty for using match
>      references,  other than the extra substitutions required for the
>      replacement strings in cases such as the example shown.

and the `#` operator is a so called "closure" or repeated match operator, equivalent to `*` in regex

as explained here http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html#l139

so basically, this parameter expansion:

```
${LBUFFER%%(#m)[_a-zA-Z0-9]#}
```

will start a regex style backreference starting at `(#m)` where any pattern matched will be available in a variable `$MATCH` like `\1` in a BRE or `$1` in a PCRE.
And because `#` is just like `*`, `[_a-zA-Z0-9]#` will match zero or many characters from the character set `[_a-zA-Z0-9]`.